Prove $((x_n, y_n))$ converges to $(x, y)$ $\in X × Y$ if and only if $(x_n)$ converges to x in X and $(y_n)$ converges to y in Y.
$(X, ⟨·, ·⟩′)$ and $(Y, ⟨·, ·⟩′′)$ are inner product spaces over the same field, $F$.
$X × Y$ is a vector field over $F$ with addition and scalar multiplication
defined by
$(x,\,y) + (x_1,\,y_1) = (x + x_1,\,y + y_1)$
$α(x,\,y) = (α\,x,\, α\,y)$
The inner product on $X × Y$ is defined as
$⟨(x,\,y), (x_1,\,y_1)⟩ = ⟨x,\, x_1⟩′ + ⟨y,\,y_1⟩′$ $\,\forall\, x, x_1 ∈ X,\, y,y_1 ∈ Y$
How do I prove  $(x_n, y_n)$ converges to $(x, y)$ $\in X × Y$ if and only if $(x_n)$ converges to $x \in X$ and $(y_n)$ converges to $y \in Y$
I am not sure how to use the inner products given or if I am allowed to state:
$|| (x_n, y_n) - (x, y)||$
$= ||(x_n, y_n) - (x_n, y) + (x_n, y) - (x, y)||$
$\leq ||(x_n, y_n) - (x_n, y)|| + ||(x_n, y) - (x, y)||$ by Triangle Inequality
$= ||(x_n, y_n - y)|| + ||(x_n - x, y)||$ (I think this step is illegal, as it's not an inner product?)
$\leq ||x_n||\cdot||y_n - y|| + ||y_n||\cdot||x_n - x||$ by CSB Inequality
etc...
Can someone advise if this is the right process? Thanks

In the step you marked you think is illegal, you have $(x_n, y_n) - (x_n, y) = (x_n - x_n, y_n - y) = (0, y_n - y)$ (and similar for the other term) by the definition of the vector addition on $X \times Y$. That should make all of the norms you are taking much simpler (and it is a short definition chase thereafter)

To add, the step where you used Cauchy Schwarz isn't correcr either.

Thanks, can you advise what the correct approach would be then please?
